# Volume of irregular piece of pie

Tags: geometry

Imagine that we cut a piece of pie with known fixed height (H). We cut it in such a way that the upper arc has angle A1 and the bottom arc has angle A2. However, we also know that the upper arc has two radii (R1 and R2) and the bottom arc has two different radii (R3 and R4). These four radii are not connected anyhow to each other (might be elliptic axis, but might be total random).

[image: Image of the piece]

Technically, if not thinking about pies, we have two polygons (with the same number of points), with mass centers a bit different from each other. The polygons lie in parallel planes so that the height value (H) is the distance between the planes. In the image the edges of the piece look vertical, but they are likely not to be perfectly vertical.
Taking two points from the upper polygon, we assume they form a local elliptic arc with two radii and angle A1. (The other arc from the same polygon will most likely have different radii values and angle). We can take two points from the lower polygon which will correspond to the two points of the upper polygon (typically, using index values) and form the lower local elliptic arc with another angle and radii values.

Thus the question is how to calculate the volume of this piece? Again, two upper radii (R1 and R2), two bottom radii (R3 and R4), fixed height (H) and two angles (A1 and A2). Note: the centers of the upper and bottom parts (essentially, polygons) might be different.

Comment: You need more information. If the arc between $R_1$ and $R_2$ is random, I cannot even calculate the area of the upper piece. Is the arc a straight line? Is it bulging inwards or outwards, and how much?

Comment: Oh yes, you are right. Well, it is assumed that the arc is formed by the circle defined by the three points: center and end points of the radius lines

Comment: But it is not a circle! You said that the $R_1$ and $R_2$ are different. So it is part of an ellipse. But center and two point do not uniquely define an ellipse

Comment: Yes, the upper and lower areas are not circles. There is a mass center and two points which define R1 and R2. These three points define a circle. Then next two points of the polygon together with the mass center define another circle. It might look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWPXM.png